# Calling filename@parse inside a command definition fails

Tags: macros, labels

I am trying to redefine `\includegraphics` to both auto-label the included figure and to restrict the maximum width. The auto-labeling is done by transforming the base filename to camelcase using the `stringstrings` package. This is what I have:

```
\usepackage{stringstrings}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\origincludegraphics=\includegraphics
\renewcommand{\includegraphics}[1]{
  \makeatletter
  \filename@parse{#1}
  \convertchar[q]{\filename@base}{\textunderscore}{\blankspace}
  \capitalizewords[q]{\thestring}
  \noblanks[q]{\thestring}
  \origincludegraphics[max width=\linewidth]{\thestring}
}
```

It fails with an

`**undefined control sequence**`

error; this seems to be coming from the file parsing commands, because this doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\testcmd[1]{
  \makeatletter
  \filename@parse{#1}
  \filename@base
  \makeatother
}

\testcmd{path/to/stuff.png}


\end{document}
```

- why doesn't file parsing work inside a command?
- is there another way to achieve my goal of figure auto-labeling by a component of the path?

Comment: You need to move `\makeatletter` (and `\makeatother`) outside of the command.

Comment: @Robert Thanks, I did that and it worked. I'm now having another problem though-- in trying to camelcase the string, I am replacing underscores with spaces, capitalizing the words, then deleting the spaces. But I can't figure out how to replace the underscores with spaces, i.e. what to use as the third argument in `\convertchar[q]{\filename@base}{\textunderscore}{ ??? }`. I tried `\blankspace`, `\quad`, and `\~` but none of them worked.